# How to detect which element was changed in form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I would like to know if there is any way to detect which element was changed in a form with jQuery. I have a form with about 40 different fields and would like to know which one of them was individually changed. All elements have a different ID. The result should give such an array with the IDs of the elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `change` handler that adds the ID to the array.

```
$(function() {
    var changed = [];
    $(":input").change(function() {
        if (changed.indexOf(this.id) == -1) {
            changed.push(this.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) and the `change` event. This should alert the id and value of any form control when it triggers the change event:

```
$("#id-of-your-form").on("change", "input, textarea, select", function() {
    var changedInput = $(this);
    alert(changedInput.attr("id"), changedInput.val());
});
```

I guess you could also add other events like `blur`, `focus` and `keypress` to capture any time the user does anything to the inputs. (e.g. `$("#id-of-your-form").on("change blur focus keypress"...`)